# Using @ElementCollection to map a column from another table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Say I have the following tables in database:

```
id | ...   (table a)
---+----
a1 | ...
a2 | ...

a_id | b_id   (mapping table a and b)
-----+----
  a1 | b1
  a1 | b2
  a2 | b2

id | value   (table b)
---+------
b1 | "one"
b2 | "two"
```

I want to map a JPA entity with Hibernate for table a:

```
@Entity
class EntityA {
    List<String> values;
}
```

so that `values` is `"one", "two"` for `"a1"` and `"two"` for `"a2"` in the example. I don't need an entity for table b, just a single column in table b to be included in `EntityA`, can this be done with `@ElementCollection` and how?

Comment: Do you really need TableB to have ids? Having ids hints that TableB actually *MAY BE* an entity. Just double-checking on the sanity of the design.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos thanks. table b is just a storage table, which is not an entity in the business logic (more like a reference data table)

Comment: I am not sure if there is any hack in JPA or any Hibernate-specific configuration to use an element collection with a join. I am afraid that you may have to turn the reference table into a full blown entity. Wait to see if someone knows more anyway. Good luck!

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos I have created a database view to join the mapping table and table b together and use element collection on that view. Not a pure JPA solution but it works.

Comment: No, actually I think it is a good solution, nice :) Maybe post an answer?

Comment: This can be done using @ElementCollection but as you have written the values in the "mapping table" both columns can have duplicates. I think if you will use '@ElementCollection' it will constrain you not to add duplicate values in one of the columns so yeah that error you will face. I am making this point here because you have written duplicate values so it will be beneficial if you use '@ManyToMany' mapping.